# MongoDB: $push a computed expression in a $group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'd like to push a computed expression onto an array instead of a value itself as part of a `$group` operation.  Can MongoDB do this?

For example, if I have a collection named `c` with documents like this:

```
{ "k" : 1, "v" : true }
{ "k" : 1, "v" : true }
{ "k" : 1, "v" : false }
{ "k" : 1, "v" : true }
{ "k" : 1, "v" : false }
```

Then I can do an aggregation like this to get all `v` values in an array:

```
db.c.aggregate({$group: {_id:'$k', vals: {$push: '$v'}}})

{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "vals" : [
                true,
                true,
                false,
                true,
                false
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

But what if instead of the actual `true` and `false` values, I'd like to change them to, say, `'red'` and `'green'`?  Perhaps something like:

```
db.c.aggregate({$group: {_id:'$k', vals: {$push: '$v' ? 'red' : 'green'}}})
```

But alas, this just outputs all `'red'`.  Is it possible to compute arbitrary values in a `$push` expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `$cond` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond ) for this:

```
db.c.aggregate( [
    { $project: {
        k: '$k',
        color: {
            $cond: [ 
                { $eq: [ '$v', true ] }, 
                'red', 
                'green'
            ]
        }
    } },
    { $group: {
        _id: '$k',
        vals: { '$push': '$color' }
    } }
] )
```

#### Edit

As another edit mentioned, it actually needs `$eq` to work since `{'$v':true}` isn't evaulated as a correct expression.

Comment: Awesome!  Actually it looks like I can even use `$cond` directly in the `$push`, without a projection: `db.c.aggregate({$group: {_id:'$k', vals: {$push: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$v', true]},'red','green']}}}})`.  Thanks.

Comment: @DoctorJ Nice, I didn't actually know that, I guess it is cos I never tried :)

Comment: great stuff. This really helped me. So many way you can do stuff with Mongo, it can be puzzling how to approach a new Aggregation